# Converting tuples to strings for the features in a machine learning study

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have DataFrame of features which I want to use in a Machine Learning algorithm. The dataframe looks like this:

[features dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUaVi.png)
I want to use this dataframe as an input for ML algorithms such as Random Forest or ANN. But I get the error of 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I think it is because of the tuples. Is there any way that I can convert all the tuples to strings?

Comment: if `t` is your tuple, have you just tried `str(t)` ?

Comment: can you supply us with a tuple example

Comment: Welcome, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide us with well formatted question and reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from a df like yours:

```
t1 = (1,2)
t2 = (3,4)
cols = ['A', 'B']
rows = []
for a in range(2):
    rows.append([t1,t2])
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
df


    A   B
0   (1, 2)  (3, 4)
1   (1, 2)  (3, 4)
```

I think the first problem is your columns, you need twice as many. Reset the columns like:

```
df.columns =  [(x+"L", x+'R') for x in df.columns]
df

    (AL, AR) (BL, BR)
0   (1, 2)  (3, 4)
1   (1, 2)  (3, 4)
```

Now from there you can simply code a loop like this:

```
newRows = []
oneRow = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    oneRow = []
    for a in range(len(row)):
        oneRow += list(row[a])
        oneRow = [str(x) for x in oneRow] #<-  this changes everything to strings
    newRows.append(oneRow)
newRows

[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4']]
```

do the same thing for the columns:

```
newCols = []
for a in range(len(df.columns)):
    newCols += list(df.columns[a])
newCols

['AL', 'AR', 'BL', 'BR']
```

and then put it all back together:

```
dfNew = pd.DataFrame(newRows, columns=newCols)
dfNew

    AL  AR  BL  BR
0   1   2   3   4
1   1   2   3   4
```

to me, I think there must be a much better way, maybe even a 1-liner, but this one works and you can move on with your analysis.

Answer (score -2):

My Python is really rusty but here's my attempt:

Say you have a tuple, tup:

```
tup = (1,2,3,4)
```

There's a special operator '*', which unpacks tuples (there's also a double star '**').

You can use it to unpack your tuples and then save them into lists:

```
list_ = [*tup]
```

Very simple!

Now if you want to turn the list_ into a string, there's a zillion options:

```
string_ = "".join(list_)
```

The "" means, join the list using nothing as a separator.

Hope that does it!

edit: the intermediate step isn't necessary, you can just do `"".join(tup)`, but I suspected you needed a list more than a string

Comment: 1. A list is not required to join, 2. Iterable elements must be strings. 3. Your syntax is invalid, and 4. This does not answer the question.

Comment: 1. see my edit, 2 What do you mean? 3. OK lol, fixed it. 4.  Yeah he said convert all the tuples but he didn't provide any code, my answer was just trying to show him so way to do it and he can do the rest I'm sure.

Comment: @coldspeed Also, don't hate on me, I'm just trying to get some reputation so I can participate on stuff... geee